# Play! framework: get controller's component/field/object between requests

Tags: java, playframework, httpcontext, playframework-2.5

I'm new to Play! and during working within a project I came with the follow situation:

I have a controller `HomeController` which has two main actions:

```
public CompletationStage<Result> search(String query){
  return docSearcher.search(query).thenApplyAsync((json) -> {               
     return ok(json);
  }, ec);
}

public CompletationStage<Result> zoom(){
    return docSearcher.zoom().thenApplyAsync((json) -> {                
     return ok(json);
  }, ec);
}
```

The `search` action receives a `query` parameter and delegates to `docSearcher` to do a DB search (`docSearcher` is injected into the controller).
The `zoom` action should provide a zoom in/out in the visualization redered as HTML.

The problem is: the `docSearcher` constructor creates a instance of a `QuadTree` which will be used to perform zoom efficiently, so this `QuadTree` instance should be available to `zoom` action after calling `search` action. The way it is, a single `QuadTree` in `docSearcher` is shared among clients/threads. I would like to have a `QuadTree` per `search` action request and share this new created `QuadTree` with subsequent `zoom` actions.

How can I achieve it using Play!? I'm not sure how can I store user data (`QuadTree` depends of user query and I don't want to build a new tree for each request, I want to share `QuadTree`s among search/zoom requests).

Thanks.

Follow the code of `docSearcher` class:

```
public class LocalDocumentSearcher implements DocumentSearcher {

  private QuadTree quadTree; 

  @Inject
  public LocalDocumentSearcher(Database db, DatabaseExecutionContext context) {
    this.executionContext = context;
    this.quadTree = initQuadTree();
}

  @Override
  public CompletionStage<String> search(String query) throws Exception {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {            
            return searchData(queryData);
    }, executionContext);
}

  @Override
  public CompletionStage<String> zoom() throws Exception {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {            
            return zoomData();
    }, executionContext);
}
```